# What is the definition of topological when talking about topological phases of matter?

Tags: topological-field-theory, topological-order

What is the definition of topological when talking about topological phases of matter? Why do people think that the fractional quantum hall effect is topological? I think it means that the ground state degeneracy depends on the topology of the material, whether it is a doughnut or not, and that you cannot measure which ground state the material is in with a local measurement. Is that correct?

Comment: See discussions in  http://physics.stackexchange.com/questions/70728/reconciling-topological-insulators-and-topological-order