# What makes a topological insulator topological?

Tags: condensed-matter, topology, topological-insulators, quantum-hall-effect, insulators

I understand that a topological insulator is one with an insulating bulk and conducting surface but I don't understand why or how the topological part comes into it. All of the resources I've found don't explain the reason behind the name or how topology plays a role. Could someone offer an explanation?

Comment: See [Reconciling topological insulators and topological order](https://physics.stackexchange.com/q/70728/49107) and [“Topological” notions in physics](https://physics.stackexchange.com/q/144115/49107).

Comment: The word 'topological' comes into it because one performs an algebraic topology of Hamiltonians on Hilbert space (after suitable interpretation), and one finds a non-trivial set of path-connected components.

Comment: @PPR "Performs an algebraic topology of Hamiltonians on Hilbert space" is a meaningless statement. This comment does nothing but confuse the reader.

Comment: If "performs an algebraic topology of Hamiltonians on Hilbert space" intimidates you, you may instead think of "define a topology on the appropriate space of local insulating Hamiltonians and compute its set of path connected components."